# PDF Map Overlay for Android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, pdf

I'm working on an indoor localisation app based on BLE Beacons, where drawing people's positions onto a floorpan is a requirement. On iOS I found the Footprint Example which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html

It utilises Apples Map Kit and PDF Maps along with some helper classes to scale and draw the Overlay on a MapView, which seems to work fine and is exactly what I need.

Unfortunately I'm not able to find something similar for android. 
The question is: Has anyone found a similar sample project, documentation or simple framework for android to handle this task?

The sample, documentation or framework should cover mapping & aligning a PDF on Google Map including pdfPoint to Lat/Long conversion.

Comment: did you find any for android?