# Google Maps Android API: Draw polygon based on pixels known from GroundOverlay's PNG

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm adding a PNG file as an own floorplan on top of Google Maps with the Google Maps Android API with the following code:

```
GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions();
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("building-d.png");
groundOverlayOptions.image(bitmapDescriptor);
groundOverlayOptions.anchor(0, 1);

LatLng buildingSW = new LatLng(47.014815, 8.305098);
LatLng buildingNE = new LatLng(47.015148, 8.305440);
LatLng buildingNW = new LatLng(47.015168, 8.305144);
LatLng buildingSE = new LatLng(47.014792, 8.305385);

Location swLoc = locationFromLatLng(buildingSW);
Location seLoc = locationFromLatLng(buildingSE);
Location nwLoc = locationFromLatLng(buildingNW);
Location neLoc = locationFromLatLng(buildingNE);

float angle = swLoc.bearingTo(nwLoc);
groundOverlayOptions.bearing(angle);

float width = swLoc.distanceTo(seLoc);
groundOverlayOptions.position(buildingSW, width);

mMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlayOptions);
```

Now I know that in the PNG there is a room at pixel coordinates 422/301, 708/301, 422/10 and 708/10 (those are the corners). I'd like to draw a polygon over the `GroundOverlay` covering that room. How should I do that? Do I need to convert my pixel-coordinates to `LatLng` and if so, how?

And by the way: Do I really have to use PNGs for `GroundOverlay`s and is there no other supported vector-format like eps, pdf, ...?

Comment: just a simple question before going to deep and complex discussions:
Do you need to add rooms dinamically or the rooms are set one time and always there?

Comment: I think rooms will always be there but need to be extracted with x/y positions from the image. I can't provide LatLng values for the corners unfortunately.

Comment: the fact is that, if you draw the rooms one time in the life (or 1 time a year) it is more convenient to temporary add a map click listener, click on the corners of the room and put in logcat the coordinates where you click. Then write the code to draw the room and you are fine. If you need something more realtime or dynamic, you have to know the distance in meters from an origin point (we can use the bottom left point for conveniency) and then you can calculate coordinates. With pixels is impossbile to do a nice work, because you don't know how gmaps calculate the positions.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Regarding pixels, I share your opinion that it's not feasible at all. That's why I asked whether it was possible to add a floorplan based on a PDF and work with 'Points' instead of pixels (as in this familiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787520/pdf-map-overlay-for-android). Using pixels (or points) instead of LatLng would have the advantage of being a bit less dependant from GPS and have a thighter coupling to the actual floorplan.

Comment: mmm i don't think you can use PDF and I would not use it. I've done several of these things in past and i've always used meters as a unit of measure. Maps are basically floorplans and everything has a size (in meters). Using coordinate systems like Mercator that works in meters instead of GPS you can georeference everything. Then you just need to transform the coordinate from meters to GPS, but that's a common task online.

Comment: Alright, so you'd suggest to work with Mercator. But all the APIs rely on LatLng values. Are there tutorials you would recommend on how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen your comment to the other answer, let me complete with some code:

Having set the "origin" in latlng 47.014816, 8.305098, you have to convert those coordinates to mercator and you can do something similar to the below:

```
public boolean initializeByTwoCouplesOfCooordsAndScale(double[] coordAreal, double[] coordBreal, double[] coordAvirtual, double[] coordBvirtual, double scalingFactor) {
    if (coordAreal[0] == coordBreal[0] && coordAvirtual[1] == coordBvirtual[1] && coordAreal[1] == coordBreal[1] && coordAvirtual[0] == coordBvirtual[0]) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates must not be the same!");
        return false;
    }
    // aPoint is considered the "origin" point (0,0)
    aPoint = coordAreal;
    bPoint = coordAvirtual;
    // now calculate the angle of the Real world coordinate for the points
    double deltaRy = coordBreal[1] - coordAreal[1];
    double deltaRx = coordBreal[0] - coordAreal[0];
    double aR = Math.atan2(deltaRy, deltaRx);
    // Now calculate the angle of the virtual world coordinates
    double deltaVy = coordBvirtual[1] - coordAvirtual[1];
    double deltaVx = coordBvirtual[0] - coordAvirtual[0];
    double aV = Math.atan2(deltaVy, deltaVx);
    // Set the transformation angle as the difference between the real and the virtual angles.
    mPhi= (aR - aV);
    // Set the scaling factor as the provided one
    mScale = (scalingFactor);//scaling factor is in function below
    // Calculate the scaling factor error correction using the distances of the two systems.
    return true;
}
```

public static double getScalingFactor(double latitude) {
        return 1 / (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)));
    }

So you can call the method:

```
initializeByTwoCouplesOfCooordsAndScale(new double[]{MERCATOR_LNG,MERCATOR_LAT},//real coordinates for point A REMEMBER: LNG,LAT = x,y!
new double[]{0d,0d}, //Virual coordinates for point A
new double[]{MERCATOR_POINT_B_LNG, MERCATOR_POINT_B_LAT},//real point B
new double[]{X_METERS,Y_METERS},//coordinates in meters of point B in virtual map
getScalingFactor(47.014816));
```

then you can transform with this function:

```
public double[] transform(double[] coord) {
        double[] transCoord = new double[2];
    double xscaled = (coord[0] - bPoint[0]) * mScale; // XXX bPoint is the position of origin point in the "VIRTUAL" world. [0] is the x coordinate
    double yscaled =  (coord[1] - bPoint[1]) * mScale;

    transCoord[0] = (xscaled * Math.cos(mPhi)) - (yscaled * Math.sin(mPhi)) + aPoint[0]; //aPoint is the point with real coordinates of origin!
    transCoord[1] = (xscaled * Math.sin(mPhi)) + (yscaled * Math.cos(mPhi)) + aPoint[1];
    return transCoord;
}
```

you can find online a way to convert latlng to mercator, it just a bunch of math ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Please give me some time to try out your formula. I'll accept the answer as soon as I've found the time to test it.

Comment: Strange... I used your methods and applied the following values as parameters: `new double[]{447184.37, 5207044.86}, new double[]{0d, 0d}, new double[]{447188.21, 5207083.95}, new double[]{25.77, 62.72}, getScalingFactor(47.014816)`. But the resulting double[] from `double[] transform = mercator.transform(new double[]{8.6, 29.9});` has these values: {-208716.66, -2430065.66}. Any clue what I've done wrong? I assume the result will also be Mercator and I'll have to convert it back to LatLng in order to draw a marker at that position but a negative Mercator values looks odd.

Comment: @user3105453 Negative mercators are ok, but not in your case... Let me know the values in lat long and ill check, your mercators values seems too low

Comment: 0/0 is 47.014816, 8.305097, the north-east bound is 47.015148, 8.305440. I used http://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html to convert the LatLng values.

Comment: Ok, I'll check. Fyk we tested it using 0_0 on North West and the second point in South East, so maybe that could be the problem

Comment: i used this service to translate from GPS WGS84 to Web Mercator.
Your point 47.014816, 8.305097 (lat,lng) is converted to:
x=924519.17 y=5944492.76
The service you linked it UTM conversion, which is not the same ;)

Comment: dang, I can't find any useful weblink to convert my values. Was your intention to paste a link here and it got stripped? Could you please try it again?

Answer (score 1):

You should work in this way:
Your indoor map positions should be relative to a specific point (BOTTOM-LEFT is 0,0 let's say), then all the other positions will be relative to that point in meters, so you will endup in values under 100meters usually.

Having this you have to "move, rotate and scale" the indoor map with respect to the world.
Just take a map on a desktop which is not LAT/LNG and find the coordinates for the same indoor points you have (usually we get real and indoor position for bottom-left and top-right positions) so you can find where it should be in the world. 
Take a look also at the scaling factor (depending on the latitude, the map must be scaled)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Scale_factor

We calculate that value by doing something like 1/cos(latitudeINradians)

```
public static double getScalingFactor(double latitude) {
        return 1 / (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)));
    }
```

Let me know if you can find a way, otherwise i will search and try to strip our code

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Let's assume 0m/0m in the 2D floorplan is at LatLng(47.014816, 8.305098). How would I get the LatLng value of "2m right, 1m up"? The calculated scalingFactor is 1.4666859491214392.